# Notation for an ordered pair of stochastic processes

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, notation

There are two stochastic processes, $\{ Y_{1,t} \}$ and $\{ Y_{2,t}\}$. If I take them as an ordered pair, what notation do I use:

1. $\{(Y_{1,t},Y_{2,t})\}$,
2. $\{(Y_1,Y_2)_t\}$,
3. $(\{Y_{1,t}\},\{Y_{2,t}\})$,
4. something else?

I also want to use a shorthand to denote the pair, something like
$\{Y_t\} := \{(Y_{1,t},Y_{2,t})\}$ (corresponding to alternative 1). Also, do I need a transpose after the right bracket such as $\{Y_t\}:=\{(Y_{1,t},Y_{2,t})^\top\}$?

Comment: A bit related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/550943/

Comment: If we go with notation in Hamilton as in the answer of your link, I think option 1 cannot be used. Option 2 and option 3 may be used. I prefer the option 3. For the second question, I usually write, for example, $\mathbf{Y}_t = (Y_{1,t}, Y_{2,t})$. I don't write the transpose symbol because I think it's cumbersome but many people add this symbol as $\mathbf{Y}_t = (Y_{1,t}, Y_{2,t})^T$

Comment: @NN2, thank you! Consider making it an answer. Also, what do you think of Ben's answer?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to discuss about the notation because there will be no ending, as the notation depends on the field people work. Personally, I write $X$ or $X_t$ (without $( \cdot )$ or $\{ \cdot \}$ for stochastic processes (the parentheses or braces seem cumbersome for me). For information, I work currently in Quantitative Finance, I read a lot of books and people don't use $( \cdot )$ or $\{ \cdot \}$ (they may write, for example [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process#Mathematical_definition) , $X = \{   X_t: t \ge 0\}$ or $X =(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$

Comment: And for the vector (of processes), I use bold symbols, for example:  $\mathbf{X}_t = (X_{1,t}, X_{2,t})$  or $\mathbf{X}_t = (X_{1,t}, X_{2,t})'$  or $\mathbf{X}_t = (X_{1,t}, X_{2,t})^T$  or $\mathbf{X} = (X_{1,t}, X_{2,t})$

Comment: And return back to my first comment, I said, " **if** we go with notation in Hamilton", option 3 must be the most suitable one.

Comment: @NN2, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Option 1 makes sense --- the other two are ambiguous at best

Option 1 makes the most sense to me --- it denotes a sequence of binary vectors $(Y_{1,t}, Y_{2,t})$ for all $t$ over the appropriate (unspecified) range.  Option 2 seems to be intended to denote the same thing, but it changes the subscripts in a way that could introduce ambiguity.  Option 3 seems silly to me because it would denote a vector composed of the conjunction of two infinite sequences, without specifying how these are connected and with further ambiguity over what element you are referencing for a given value of $t$.

It is also perfectly fine to use $Y_t=(Y_{1,t}, Y_{2,t})$ to denote the bivariate vector, and if you wish to transpose this to represent a column-vector that is also fine.